# Split [cursor] into more specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, clean-up

The tag [cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursor) is used by database and screen questions (and others) likewise. Can we clean it up (e.g. rename it to [database-cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-cursor) and [mouse-cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse-cursor), which would be more relevant) and then blacklist it?

Comment: The wiki has both explanations... I personally never talk about a database-cursor or a  screen-cursor, their meaning becomes clear based on context.

Comment: @rene Tags are supposed to be meaningful on their own.