# Disambiguate caret, cursor tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, clean-up

The [caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caret) tag is currently a mix of references to [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)'s `caret` package for machine learning, and the onscreen text cursor.  (R-related questions seem to slightly outnumber cursor questions.)

Since [cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursor) exists and its [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cursor/info) mentions text cursors, it seems easy to re-tag questions about the onscreen text cursor from `caret` to `cursor`, keeping the questions about the R package as they are.

However, there was a previously an idea to split `cursor` into several tags:

[Split [cursor] into more specific tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250926/split-cursor-into-more-specific-tags)

and I don't want to start re-tagging things as `cursor` if that tag is going to disappear.  A small amount of progress looks to have been made with changing tags to [database-cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-cursor) and [mouse-cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse-cursor) and [cursor-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursor-position).

Please vote for one you favourite answer.

Comment: When I say "caret", it never refers to the mouse, but "cursor" is ambiguous.

Comment: @Louis I agree that "cursor" is ambiguous; that's the point of the linked question.  I think a `text-cursor` tag would be best, but it seems that `cursor-position` is the nearest thing that currently exists.

Comment: Do we need something like "text-cursor" or cursor at all? I mean, the implementation is based on the editor or shell you are using.

Comment: Personally when I see "caret", I think `^`.

Answer (score 31):

Change tags about questions related to the R `caret` package to `r-caret`.

Answer (score 16):

I would use `r-caret` and `text-cursor`, and move mouse cursor stuff to `mouse-cursor`, and then nuke `caret` and `cursor` to force people to disambiguate when they tag in the first place. (The appropriate tags will come up in search as they type, I believe.)

I chose `text-cursor` over `text-caret` because I think cursor is just the more popular term. I think few people will type "caret", see it isn't there, and not think to try "cursor" instead. I didn't choose `cursor-position` because that's just as ambiguous as `cursor`.

Comment: what about the caret (or hat) character?

Comment: @DanielA.White That probably doesn't need its own tag.

Comment: See also [*Split \[cursor\] into more specific tags*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250926/split-cursor-into-more-specific-tags) for disambiguation of [tag:cursor].

Answer (score 2):

Change tags on questions about the onscreen text pointer from [caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caret) to [cursor-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursor-position).  Update the `caret` tag info page.

Answer (score -5):

Change tags on questions about the onscreen text pointer from [caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caret) to [cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursor).  Update the `caret` tag info page.

Answer (score -18):

Do nothing.  Multiple meanings for [caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caret) and [cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursor) are OK because you can tell from context what they mean.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of tags.